# how to purge the nested json element to uppermost key in python without using 'key' of upper element

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

So basically, I have the following json:

```
{'firstName': {'value': 'xyz'}}
```

Now I want to convert this into:

```
{'firstName':'xyz'}
```

without using the keyname 'firstname' i.e. is there a way to purge the nested dictionary?

Comment: So is it JSON (i.e. a string) or a dict?

Comment: Also, why don't you want to use `firstName`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey it's a JSON. Actually I am calling a function:

Comment: @Aran-Fey it's a JSON.      let x={'firstName': {'value': 'xyz'}}   and y=x['firstName']     I am calling a function with input parameter as   fun(y) which assigns 'xyz' .thus I was only able to use y['value']='xyz'.

Comment: Then it's not possible. You can't modify the outer dict if you don't have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could, for datum with that type of structure

```
{'x': {'y':'z'}}
```

I would do this:

```
def removeInnerDict(to_parse_dict):
    parsed_dict = dict()

    for key, inner_dict in to_parse_dict.items():
        inner_value = list(inner_dict.values())[0]
        parsed_dict.update({key: inner_value})

    return parsed_dict
```

The function *removeInnerDict* caters for arbitrary size of dictionary, as long as you stick to the specified format